# Help verifying my proof that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists rational $\frac{j}{k}$ such that $0<\frac{j}{k}<\epsilon$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I'm trying to prove that that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists rational $\frac{j}{k}$ such that $0<\frac{j}{k}<\epsilon$. Obviously $j,k\in \mathbb{N}$. This is not for homework, it's a lemma I needed for another proof I was working on. I was trying to avoid limits.

Proof:

Assume we can fix $\epsilon$ such that there is no $\frac{j}{k}$ such that $0<\frac{j}{k}<\epsilon$. Since all the numbers with the form $\frac{1}{k}$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$) are of the form $\frac{j}{k}$ it follows that for all $k$, $\epsilon<\frac{1}{k}$, which implies that for all $k$: $k<\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ which is clearly impossible.

Q.E.D.

I always get wigged out by problems that conceptually involve infinitesimals or infinity. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe pointing out why it is 'clearly impossible' by using the Archimedean Property would be a nice addition, but aside from that, looks fine.  I agree with Marc though, direct proof would make more sense since the Archimedean property is an existence property

Comment: I didn't know about the Archimedean Property... Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems correct, although I find a direct proof more elegant here, especially as it is no more work. Choose $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then $0<\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$.

Comment: you should mention that you can do this because of the Archimidean property.

Comment: Clarity seems to escape me. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, but in my opinion "$k < \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ not for all $k\in\mathbb N$" is on the same level of "being clear" as the existence of a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{k} < \varepsilon$, so you could have just said the statement is clearly true to begin with.

A strict proof would use the Archimedean property, which guarantees the existence of a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $k>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, there are just some minor details: such as explaining that you don't fix **any** $\epsilon$, you for a contradiction assume you can fix an $\epsilon$ such that there is no fraction $\frac{j}{k}$ between $0$ and $\epsilon$.